# Pgfplots label not appearing

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ticks=none,
            xtick={-10,-9,...,10},   
            xmin=-6,
            xmax=6,
            xlabel={$\alpha$},
            axis x line=middle,
            ytick={-10,-9,...,10},
            ymin=0,
            ymax=10,
            ylabel={$s$},
            axis y line=middle,
            no markers,
            samples=100,
            domain=-10:10,
            restrict y to domain=-20:20, xscale=1.2 ]
        \addplot[green,samples=400] (x,{-1/x});
        \addplot[blue,samples=400] (x,{1/(1+2*x)});
        \addplot[red,samples=400, domain=-1:1] (x,{-4*x/(1+x)^2}) node[pos=0.5, pin=135:{$\frac{-4\alpha}{(1+\alpha^2)}$}] {};
        \draw[cyan] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs: 1,10) node[pos=1, pin = -30: {\tiny $\alpha=1$}] {};
        \draw[cyan] (axis cs:-1,0) -- (axis cs: -1,10) node[pos=0.5, pin = -120: {\tiny $\alpha=-1$}] {};
    \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My one plot label `\addplot[red,samples=400, domain=-1:1] (x,{-4*x/(1+x)^2}) node[pos=0.5, pin=135:{$\frac{-4\alpha}{(1+\alpha^2)}$}] {};` doesn't want to display for some reason.  Does anyone see a problem with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The label is outside of the axis rectangle, so it is cliped away.  You can add an option `clip=false,` to the `axis` environment, but that would "unclip" the plots of your functions, which probably isn't what you want.  Another option would be moving the red label so it is comnpletely inside of the axis rectangle.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Maybe I don't understand the pos and pin stuff. How can I get it back in the area?

Comment: @user21359 -- Try the third addplot, change 135 to -135 should bring the formula back.

Comment: I might be missing something but that still doesn't bring up the label?  Where is it that I can't see it?